# How to redirect user to a different route after a function is completed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-router, web-development-server

currently, we are in `/signup` route in a react component.
I have this function as shown below

```
    const sendForm  = async(event) => {
    try{
        var data = {
            Name : name,
            Password : password,
            Email : email,
        };
        await axios.post("api/users/", data);
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log("there was an error sending new user through post");
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

this function is inside a react component now i need to make sure after this `sendForm`  function is completed user should be redirected to `/login` route. Please help me how to do that??

Comment: Did you try out the provided example? Let me know how it went and if you need further explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `useHistory()` from React Router.

Create a routes `<Switch>` where you want to do your routing.

```js
<Switch>
  <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
</Switch>
```

Don't forget to use `<BrowserRouter />`, you can do this in `index.js`

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

When your fetch is done, you can push `/login` into history, this will redirect you.

```js
const history = useHistory();

const sendForm  = async(event) => {
  try{
      var data = {
          Name : name,
          Password : password,
          Email : email,
      };
      await axios.post("api/users/", data);
      history.push("/login"); // push route in history
  }
  catch(err){
      console.log("there was an error sending new user through post");
      console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Don't forget to import everything correctly.

You can read more about React Router and hooks [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks)